# Angularjs convert string to html in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to add links in my view. I do have links which basically contains  html tags as strings.
I tried:

```
<p data-ng-repeat='i in links' >{$ i.link $}</p>
```

which basically just deploy in my view : mylink

So I did try:

```
<p data-ng-repeat='i in links' ><span data-ng-bind-html="i.link"></span></p>
```

It doesn't work though, any idea how could I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide more details, could you expose your controller that represents it?

Comment: rather than include the html markup in your strings, use `ng-href` and have your string contain simply the URL

Comment: `ng-bind-html` should work!

Comment: when you use `ng-bind-html` or `data-ng-bind-html`, make sure you have added `ngSanitize` in ur module dependency  `angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

Comment: from the docs: ng-bind-html Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the $sce as a dependancy of the module

```
angular.module('myApp', ['$sce']);
```

When getting the links

```
angular.forEach($scope.links, function(value){
    value.link = $sce.trustAsHtml(value.link);
});
```

Using Safe Contextual Escaping (docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) and using trustAs delegate you're telling Angular that this value is safe to use within that context. In this example. $sce.trustAsHtml returns an object that angular can trust is safe to as HTML.

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: sure, using Safe Contextual Escaping (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) and using trustAs delegate you're telling Angular that this value is safe to use within that context. In this example. $sce.trustAsHtml returns an object that angular can trust is safe to as HTML.

Comment: Please use the edit button to add this to your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you'll actually want to use:

```
<p data-ng-repeat='i in links' >{{ i.link }}</p>
```

Double braces, not brace-dollar.  In the second case, `ng-bind-html` will require that you have added "ngSanitize" to your module's dependency list.

```
angular.module('yourAppNameHere', ['ngSanitize'])
```

**Edit:**

If you really do want clickable links on the page, then do pretty much what @sreeramu suggested (Though I'd see if you can't find a way to add a nice description):

```
<p data-ng-repeat='i in links' ><a ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{i.desc}}</a></p>
```

(Notice that he suggested using `ng-href`, instead of `href`.   He's right.)

Answer (score 0):

Insert `ngSanitize` as a dependency to you app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
```

But before be ensure that you are including the script `angular-sanitize.js`.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your links have already got the a tags with it so in this case you do not need to re-add the a tags...

In this case do this...

Add this to you scripts (**include acc. to your angular version**)

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-
sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Add this to your **app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('modulename', [ 'ngSanitize']);
```

And than in your view do this
If it is the div that you want the link to attach to...

```
<div ng-bind-html="i.link"></div>
```

The above would give you something as this

```
<div><a href='your link'></a></div>
```